# Cut multiple parts of a video with ffmpeg

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

In what I'm trying to do, I need to remove some parts of a video file, and create a new one from that.

**For example**, from a video file like this:

```
===================
```

I make two cuts

```
======||=====||||==
```

and generate a new smaller video file:

```
=============
```

And when I say 2, I mean an arbitrary number of separate cuts, depending on the video file.

If I wanted to cut just one part I would do:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:03.500 -to 00:00:08.500 -async 1 cut.mp4 -y
```

Which works perfectly. I could perhaps do this many times and then join all the cuts together... But this is very inefficient for larger video files.

To make two cuts I was looking at **filter_complex**. I've been trying to get it right for hours but I can't seem to get this working :/

If I do something like this I get a video with no audio:

```sh
command='ffmpeg -i video.mp4
                -filter_complex "[0]trim=start_frame=10:end_frame=20[v0];
                                 [0]trim=start_frame=30:end_frame=40[v1];
                                 [v0][v1]concat=n=2[v5]"
                -map [v5] -async 1 output.mp4'
```

If I try to do this, things get all messed up:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 
       -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start_frame=10:end_frame=20[v0];
                        [0:a]atrim=start=10:end=20[a0];
                        [0:v]trim=start_frame=30:end_frame=40[v1];
                        [0:a]atrim=start=30:end=40[a1];
                        [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=2:v=1:a=1[v5][a]" \
       -map [v5] -map [a] -async 1 output.mp4
```

I even trying to to this in Python with **ffmpeg-python** https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python but I also can't get audio to work.

Can anyone give me some help on this?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: As a side note, when using the `-ss` before the `-i` option, ffmpeg tries to seek to that position without bothering decompressing every single frame to that point.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The select filter is better for this.

```sh
ffmpeg -i video \
       -vf "select='between(t,4,6.5)+between(t,17,26)+between(t,74,91)',
            setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" \
       -af "aselect='between(t,4,6.5)+between(t,17,26)+between(t,74,91)',
            asetpts=N/SR/TB" out.mp4
```

select and its counterpart filter is applied to the video and audio respectively. Segments selected are times 4 to 6.5 seconds, 17 to 26 seconds and finally 74 to 91 seconds. The timestamps are made continuous with the setpts and its counterpart filter..

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I've been looking for! Thank!

Comment: Related: given two equal length files input files with `-i a.mp4 -i b.mp4`, select the 1st one for a couple seconds (between 5 and 8 seconds into the videos) with `-filter_complex "sendcmd='5-8 [enter] streamselect map 0, [leave] streamselect map 1',streamselect=map=1"`  You can put a `scale=...` after that if they aren't both the same resolution. e.g. multiple angles of the same scene, cut to another angle then cut back.  (I didn't use `astreamselect` so it doesn't switch audio streams, just video.)  [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#streamselect_002c-astreamselect)

Comment: Why do we need setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB ?

Comment: For smooth timestamps i.e. frames spaced at equal intervals in time.

Comment: Is it possible to alter this in anyway to make the seeking work as quickly as -ss...-to? Using -ss to cut a single section from a long file is very fast.

Comment: This works great but after the final video is created, ffmpeg doesn't terminate for some reason, and I need to force stop the process in order to get the final video. Is there a solution?

Comment: Share full command and its log of what you tried.

Comment: @Gyan for some videos (all mp4) works great, but for others I get `Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_select_0' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_asetpts_1' filter input pad 0 (audio)` and `Cannot create the link select:0 -> asetpts:0` any idea why this happens?

Comment: It's imprecise when I speed up videos output. `ffmpeg -i tt107b.mp4 -vf "select='between(t,24,119)+between(t,138,564)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,crop=1418:916:502:40,setsar=1,setpts=PTS*0.05" -r 50 -b:v 5000k tt107b-.mp4`. I need to find borders iteratively.

Comment: How can I with a single command cut into separate files where some of the output files have jump cuts, that is, they're concatenations of some of the cut segments? For example, I want to with a single command (so there's only one seeking through the input file) cut out segments a, b, c, and d and create output files where the first one is concatenation of a+b and the second, c+d?