# Is there a way to include a transition video when using ffmpeg's select filter?

Tags: select, ffmpeg, trim

I wanted to take some segments of an input video and make a highlight reel automatically using ffmpeg. I was originally experimenting with trimming and concating but it was difficult because the audio was falling out of sync and also I have a variable number of highlights that I want.

I discovered from the [top comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594412/cut-multiple-parts-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg) that the 'select' filter is very powerful. I have a python program that inputs all the parts I want selected into the command and run it in the terminal and it works perfect. Only issue is that I want a quick transition video to play in between each of these highlights. Is this not possible with select? Do I have to return to using trim and concat? Thank you!

Edit: for reference, here is an example ffmpeg command I am running

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -vf "select='between(t,56,69)+between(t,60,135)+between(t,73,132)+between(t,152,163)+between(t,251,278)+between(t,600,700)+between(t,774,872)', setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB " -af "aselect='between(t,56,69)+between(t,60,135)+between(t,73,132)+between(t,152,163)+between(t,251,278)+between(t,600,700)+between(t,774,872)',asetpts=N/SR/TB" output.mp4
```

Comment: This is a question about ffmpeg, so the python stuff is just in the way. Can you show an example command as executed and not just the scripted implementation of the command in python?

Comment: @llogan Updated, thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate what the "quick transition video" is?

Comment: @llogan In theory any video would do, just something short to mark the end of one clip, I'm thinking I could use a segment of this blooper real effect video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvm6avc8Zwo I would just include a 'transition.mp4' video in my working directory