# Audio and Video not synced after cut multiple parts - FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I follow the solution from this question when trying to cut multiple parts of a video, [Cut multiple parts of a video with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594412/cut-multiple-parts-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg). But the problem is, if I cut more than several times (like around 20 times or more) the video and audio will not synced.

This is the base line I use:

```
  ffmpeg -i video \
       -vf "select='between(t,4,6.5)+between(t,17,26)+between(t,74,91)',
            setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" \
       -af "aselect='between(t,4,6.5)+between(t,17,26)+between(t,74,91)',
            asetpts=N/SR/TB" out.mp4
```

Comment: What's the framerate of your video?

Comment: Frame rate 23.98 fps

Audio :
Bit rate 127kbps
Audio sample rate 44.100 kHz

Answer (score 0):

First, the explanation. The main culprit is the framerate: 23.98 = 24000/1001 fps. For your example of `between(t,4,6.5)`, these timestamps in seconds convert to 95.904-th frame and 155.844-th frame, neither frame exists. Assuming `select` picks the nearest frames (it could truncate, but you get the idea): it actually sets the cut boundary at frame 96 = 4.004 s and frame 156 = 6.5065 s. Meanwhile, `aselect` can pick the exact audio samples at any integer or half second. So, in this example, the selected audio samples account for the exact 2.5 seconds you specified while the video frames span 2.5025 s, so the latter is longer by 2.5 ms. While this amounts of sync-loss may not be noticeable, this error compounds when you make 20 cuts.

So, how to fix this? There are 2 ways I could think of:

1. Adjust all video `select` timing to the (near-)exact frame time. Like the example above, calculate the nearest frame time on all your cuts and use them on both `select` and `aselect`. Just in case, the formula is `t = round(t_desired*24000/1001)*1001/24000`. The audio samples may not align to the adjusted time but each cut only introduces less than `1/44100 = 22.68 us` error. This shouldn't be noticeable, even compounded by 20 cuts
2. Change the video framerate by prepending an `fps=24` filter in front of `select` filter. This framerate guarantees the frames to align to integer/half/quarter seconds. If 23.98 fps is required, you can also add `-r 24000/1001` output option to revert back to the original rate.

Hopefully, one of these will help your case.